# Can a link between photons that don't exist at the same time provide communication with the past?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement, speed

They have published something about [a link between photons that don't exist at the same time](http://news.sciencemag.org/sciencenow/2013/05/physicists-create-quantum-link-b.html?ref=hp). Does this means that it is possible to build a device that will receive messages from itself but these messages will be received earlier than they will be sent? Can someone operating this device can win the lottery? How would you describe in numbers the bandwidth of such device? Larger than infinite? Negative?

Comment: If you think it's impossible, please try to answer the other questions as if it was possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The global answer is "No".

You cannot go back into past, you cannot receive a message before you send it, you cannot win the lottery, and so on.

Photon Entanglement are only special correlations (quantum correlations).

This does not violate causality, and this does not allow you to send a message faster than light.

Let's take a basic example about correlations, in this case a simple classical correlation.

Suppose you love your girl-friend, and your girl-friend loves you. This is a correlation.

Now, you can live your country, very far from your girl-friend, and even die.

But, if we ask to your girl-friend : Do you love Jader Dias, she will say : Yes.

This will not depends on time, this will not depends on spatial relative distance between your girl-friend and you, this will no depend if you are alive or not, this is a correlation.

Comment: Someone must tell RFC about this: http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6921.txt

Comment: Yes, that's funny, but it does not work.